# Store Apache access logs to MySQL

Tags: mysql, apache, logging

I referred this [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-logging-to-a-mysql-database-with-mod_log_sql-on-debian-etch) to log access information into mysql database.

Below is my database structure for

> apachelogs.web_access_log

```
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id               | char(19)             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| agent            | varchar(255)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bytes_sent       | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| child_pid        | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cookie           | varchar(255)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| machine_id       | varchar(25)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| request_file     | varchar(255)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| referer          | varchar(255)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| remote_host      | varchar(50)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| remote_logname   | varchar(50)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| remote_user      | varchar(50)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| request_duration | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| request_line     | varchar(255)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| request_method   | varchar(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| request_protocol | varchar(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| request_time     | char(28)             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| request_uri      | varchar(255)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| request_args     | varchar(255)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| server_port      | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ssl_cipher       | varchar(25)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ssl_keysize      | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ssl_maxkeysize   | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status           | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time_stamp       | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| virtual_host     | varchar(255)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I see most of the column values are NULL as below when the request is received from browser:

```
+------+-------+------------+-----------+--------+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------+----------------+--------+------------+--------------+
| id   | agent | bytes_sent | child_pid | cookie | machine_id | request_file | referer | remote_host | remote_logname | remote_user | request_duration | request_line | request_method | request_protocol | request_time | request_uri | request_args | server_port | ssl_cipher | ssl_keysize | ssl_maxkeysize | status | time_stamp | virtual_host |
+------+-------+------------+-----------+--------+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------+----------------+--------+------------+--------------+
| -    | -     |          0 |      NULL | NULL   | NULL       | NULL         | -       | ::1         | NULL           | -           |                0 | NULL         | NULL           | HTTP/1.0         | NULL         | NULL        | NULL         |        NULL | NULL       |        NULL |           NULL |    408 | 1531980584 | 192.168.4.18 |
+------+-------+------------+-----------+--------+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------+----------------+--------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Most of the request parameters are missing. Let me know what I have to modify in order to log all the attributes with their corresponding values.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache2 is unable to write the logs to MySQL database properly due to the mismatch of 'id' column width. The default width created in the `web_access_log` table is 19 which should be increased to 25. If 25 did not help try again with bigger width.

After doing this, the MySQL log automatically started updating without any further issues.